# How to make sure a user performs an action in an iframe

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, task

I have an iframe where a user has to perform a task and when the task is completed it will show another iframe where the user will perform a task and after that is completed a button will show

So I need to know how to
- Check the current url of an iframe
then
- When the users url = example.com hide the iframe and show another
then
- When the user completes the task stated above a button will show

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of the urls that you're referencing inside the iframe are on the same domain, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("id_of_iframe").contentWindow.location.href
```

However if they refer to a different domain you'll run into security/cross domain issues.